# What are SUCCESS and part-r-00000 files in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Although I use Hadoop frequently on my Ubuntu machine I have never thought about `SUCCESS` and `part-r-00000` files. The output always resides in `part-r-00000` file, but what is the use of `SUCCESS` file? Why does the output file have the name `part-r-0000`? Is there any significance/any nomenclature or is this just a randomly defined?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

See http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2010/08/what%E2%80%99s-new-in-apache-hadoop-0-21/

> On the successful completion of a job, the MapReduce runtime creates a _SUCCESS file in the output directory. This may be useful for applications that need to see if a result set is complete just by inspecting HDFS. (MAPREDUCE-947)

This would typically be used by job scheduling systems (such as OOZIE), to denote that follow-on processing on the contents of this directory can commence as all the data has been output.

**Update** (in response to comment)

The output files are by default named part-x-yyyyy where:

- `x` is either 'm' or 'r', depending on whether the job was a map only job, or reduce
- `yyyyy` is the mapper or reducer task number (zero based)

So a job which has 32 reducers will have files named part-r-00000 to part-r-00031, one for each reducer task.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the output file is called `part-r-00000`, though, or whether this is even necessarily always the case.

Comment: Updated to specifically address @KyleStrand comment

Comment: Note that: currently (`hadoop-streaming-2.4.0.2.1.1.0`) there's no `x` if you happen to use hadoop-streaming. So it's gonna be like `part-00000`.

Comment: Some result sets have _SUCCESS files, and some don't. For instance, when using SAVE from Pig, is there an option that one needs to set for _SUCCESS file to be created when done?