# use of part-m-00000 in multiple output format in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, multipleoutputs

whats the use of part-m-00000 file in multipleoutput format in hadoop.

I tried to create multiple file but not full data is present, combining all multiple output files. and part-m -00000 file is 0 Bytes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666488/what-are-success-and-part-r-00000-files-in-hadoop Check this answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put `LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextOutputFormat.class);`
under job to get rid of part-m-00000. Can you elaborate more on "not full data is present"?